# Compare old VS new variables in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to compare an old value in a `<td>` with the new value entered by the end user. I'm using `ng-blur` to detect when there is focus out of the field rather than calling the function. The problem is I can't get this very simple logic to work and I can't figure out why.

This is my table:

```
<main ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
        <p ng-model="old">{{old}}</p>
        <thead>
        <th>user name</th>
        <th>script name</th>
        <th>cron format<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Min|Hour|Day Of Month|Month|Day Of Week"></span></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,script_id) in data">
        <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in script_id">
            <td class="userName">{{user(user_id)}}</td>
            <td class="scriptName">{{script(script_id)}}</td>
            <td class="cronFormat"><input type="text" ng-model="cron_format" ng-blur="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)"/></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and this is the comparison :

```
$scope.old = $scope.cron_format = "";

$scope.saveCron(user_id, script_id, cron_format) {
    if ($scope.old == $scope.cron_format) {
        return; //value was unchanged
    }
        $.post("updateCronChange.php", "user_id=" + userId + "&script_id=" + scriptId + "&cron_format=" + cronFormat, function (data) {
            alert('cron format changed to:' + cronFormat);
        });
    $scope.old = $scope.cron_format;
});
```

Currently, the function executes each time the field is out of focus. What am I missing here?

Comment: can't you just do:  ng-blur="!saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)"

Comment: maybe im missing something but where is the solution for comparison here? executing both times or not doesnt get me anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` for each iteration of the `ng-repeat` to store the old value, and then use it in the function to compare:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data" ng-init="oldCron = row.cron_format">
```

And in the function call:

```
ng-click="saveCron(row.user_id,row.script_id,row.cron_format,oldCron)"
```

And finally inside the function itself:

```
$scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat,oldCron){
        console.log("old cron: " + oldCron);            
        console.log("new cron: " + cronFormat);            
        if (oldCron != cronFormat) {

            //assign
        }

    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s5y3fhu/2/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to save an old value and print it out. You can try changing it to this -

```
if ($scope.old != $scope.cron_format) {
   $.post("updateCronChange.php", "user_id=" + userId + "&script_id=" + scriptId + "&cron_format=" + cronFormat, function(data) {
     alert('cron format changed to:' + cronFormat);
  });
  $scope.old = $scope.cron_format;
}
```

Here is a working example if you like -

```js
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = '';
    $scope.old = '';
    $scope.getNewValue = 'false'

    $scope.saveModel = function(value) {
      if ($scope.old != value) {
        $scope.getNewValue = 'true';
        $scope.old = value;
        $scope.myModel = '';
        // Here you can do your post request
      } else {        
        $scope.getNewValue = 'false';
      }
    };

  }
]);
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test'>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">Enter Some Text
    <input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-blur="saveModel(myModel)">
    <p>Old Value - {{old}}</p>
    <p>Current Value - {{myModel}}</p>
    <p class="green">Get New Value - {{getNewValue}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```